# Publish single Google Sheet to the web

Tags: google-sheets

I have many sheets in one spreadsheet. How do I publish single spreadsheet to the web?

When I attempt to publish, it doesn't show any option to pick the sheets I want to publish.

[image: dialog]

Comment: Do you want to publish a single spreadsheet,  or just one workworksheet from it?   If the latter, then I think you need to copy it to a separate spreadsheet file and publish that.

Answer (score 3):

This (presumable) oversight has since been corrected: here is the current screenshot of publishing a new Google Sheets document.

[image: publish]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not presently possible with new Google Sheets. There have been complaints about this [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearch/new%2420sheets%2420publish%2420single%2420sheet/docs/Hhaeq9K3Q8g) and the signs are this may have been 'oversight' rather than a deliberate crippling`*`. As the consequences for some could be serious it looks to me as though the facility will, at some point, be reinstated.

`*` for example, one would hope that if intentional it would have been mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3543688?rd=1).

Answer (score 0):

You might check out Cloudward's Cloud Snippets.

They have a snippet that allows you to publish a Google Sheet as a list to the web. If you know some HTML/CSS you can further customize before publishing. They have lots of Snippets to check out. Here's one that might help: https://snippets.cloudward.com/app_listing.espx?template_id=0d367025e8b5f402cd510905cade1d29&account_id=&cat_id=c478885bb325028151eaa9060422c67f